# Multi Pipes in C

Tags: c, pipe

I have a homework which is writing 
own shell. so, I try to connect three 
pipes in c, but I cant. like this

```
/bin/cat  a.txt  |   /usr/bin/wc -l  |    /usr/bin/wc -l
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried and why didn't it work? Did you read `fork(2)` and `pipe(2)`?

Comment: Chaining two line counts like that will make the end result be 1, since the middle wc will only ever return a single line with a single number in it.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that each command executes in its own process, each of which inherits the STDIN, STDOUT, and STDERR I/O streams from your shell. So you must create the pipes and redirect them to the I/O streams or each subprocess prior to forking each subprocess.

Comment: +1 excellent answer, providing guidance and a general layout of the solution without actual code.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.scsh.net/docu/scsh-paper/scsh-paper-Z-H-4.html#%_sec_2 Provides an excellent overview of this very process.